# How do I see all images for all Wikipedia pages in a specific category?

Tags: wikipedia, images

For example, let's say I want to see a list of all Wikipedia pages in the [category "Trees"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Trees) with the first image list in each article.

Does Wikipedia provide any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this natively in Wikipedia however the [PetScan tool](https://petscan.wmflabs.org/) can do this, as well as many other things.

> ##### [Wikipedia > PetScan](https://meta.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/PetScan/en)
>
> PetScan is a tool that allows users
> to extract data, generate lists of Wikipedia (and related projects)
> pages or Wikidata items that match certain criteria, such as all pages
> in a certain category, or all items with a certain property, extract
> and analyze data from Wikimedia projects. PetScan can also combine
> some temporary lists (here called "sources") in various ways, to
> create a new one.

- [PetScan Tool](https://petscan.wmflabs.org/)
- [PetScan Manual (Wikipedia)](https://meta.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/PetScan/en)
- [PetScan's Rationale (Magnus Manske)](http://magnusmanske.de/wordpress/?p=385)

### Example using PetScan

1. In the **Categories** tab set:

   1. **Project** to **Wikipedia**
   2. **Depth** to a non-zero number
   3. **Categories** to **Trees**
2. In the **Output** tab, enable **images** by checking its box.

[Prefilled example link](https://petscan.wmflabs.org/?outlinks_any=&edits%5Banons%5D=both&links_to_no=&subpage_filter=either&interface_language=en&cb_labels_any_l=1&templates_any=&show_disambiguation_pages=both&before=&search_max_results=500&search_filter=&wpiu=any&larger=&language=en&wikidata_prop_item_use=&ores_prob_from=&labels_no=&links_to_any=&depth=0&source_combination=&active_tab=tab_output&cb_labels_no_l=1&smaller=&show_soft_redirects=both&wikidata_label_language=&add_image=on&edits%5Bflagged%5D=both&common_wiki_other=&sitelinks_any=&min_redlink_count=1&categories=Trees&min_sitelink_count=&max_age=&ores_prob_to=&edits%5Bbots%5D=both&langs_labels_no=&common_wiki=auto&after=&project=wikipedia&page_image=any&ns%5B0%5D=1&cb_labels_yes_l=1&doit=) with variables and results for the requested category **Trees** on English **Wikipedia**.<sup>*****</sup>

<sup>*****</sup> [Credit: @Juandev](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/309012/juandev)

Comment: As mentioned above, you can use the Petscan tool. As of March 2023, it works. [This link](https://petscan.wmflabs.org/?outlinks_any=&edits%5Banons%5D=both&links_to_no=&subpage_filter=either&interface_language=en&cb_labels_any_l=1&templates_any=&show_disambiguation_pages=both&before=&search_max_results=500&search_filter=&wpiu=any&larger=&language=en&wikidata_prop_item_use=&ores_prob_from=&labels_no=&links_to_any=&depth=0&source_combination=&active_tab=tab_output&cb_labels_no_l=1&smaller=&show_soft_redirects=both&wikidata_label_language=&add_image=on&edits%5Bflagged%5D=both&common_wiki_other=&si